# Function to return a global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, global-variables

I feel like this is really easy, but I can not figure it out.

I want to set the currentUserId inside of the getCurrentUser function, which I would like to be able to call inside other functions.

Below is what I have now, and it returns undefined. What am I missing?

```
var currentUserId;

function getCurrentUser()   {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/set_user',
        success: function(result)   {
            currentUserId = result.id;
            return currentUserId;
        },
        error: function(err)    {
            console.log(err);
        }

    })
};

getCurrentUser();
console.log("current user id is " + currentUserId);
```

Comment: your console.log happens before the ajax has finished

Comment: @naortor you're exactly right -- i'm seeing this in my console. How do I solve this? The ultimate goal is to be able to call this function, and user the variable currentUserId in other functions

Comment: You can set `async: false`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: simply follow this link for precise example if you wanna make it synchronous http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re or use callback pattern to do something when response received

Comment: **Don't make it synchronous.**   Refactor to work *with* async, not against it.  If you need it sooner, then set it as part of the page render from the server-side (whatever tech is used, not stated in the question), or disable/hide page functionality/content until complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because inside `getCurrentUser` method you are doing an asynchronous AJAX call, so the value is not yet ready when you print it with `console.log`.

The value will be correctly set when the `GET /set_user` request will end successfully, only in that case the function:

```
    success: function(result)   {
        currentUserId = result.id;
        return currentUserId;
    }
```

will be executed and `currentUserId` will be set.

Based on [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation, the value returned by `$.ajax` call is a Promise. So first, return the promise to the caller (1) and then wait the promise is resolved to print the value (2).

```
var currentUserId;

function getCurrentUser()   {
    return $.ajax({ // 1. Return the Promise here
        type: "GET",
        url: '/set_user',
        success: function(result)   {
            currentUserId = result.id;
            return currentUserId;
        },
        error: function(err)    {
            console.log(err);
        }

    })
};

// 2. Then wait the call to succeed before print the value (use the 'done' method)
getCurrentUser().done(function() {
  console.log("current user id is " + currentUserId);    
});
```

Comment: I think this is the solution. I updated it, and I am now getting an error "cannot read property 'done' of undefined. Working through that error. Any thoughts as to what that issue is? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Try to use `then` instead of `done`.

Comment: .then doesn't work either. There is .done being used in the app already, so it's possible, but the whole function is coming back undefined. Jquery version: 1.11.3

Comment: I could not find the difference between what I wrote to duplicate your answer, and your actual answer. So I copied and pasted, and voila. Something must have been a hair off. Thank you so much!! It works perfectly now. :)

Answer (score 2):

Like Andrea explain, the value was not ready yet when you make a ajax call.

One way to avoid this is use callback:

```js
function getCurrentUser(callback)   {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/set_user',
        success: function(result)   {
            var currentUserId = result.id;
            if (callback)
              callback(currentUserId);
        },
        error: function(err)    {
            console.log(err);
        }

    })
};

function displayResult(userId){
  console.log("current user id is " + userId);   
}

getCurrentUser(displayResult);
```

And this will also avoid the use of globe variable currentUserId.